# a question about passive voice grammar

Tags: grammar, differences, passive-voice

What is the difference between "get/got/gotten" and "am/is/was/are/were/be/have or has been" in the (Passive Voice) grammar?

For example:

> My computer gets/got/gotten damaged.

and

> My computer is/was/has been damaged.

And what about if I mix with them in a sentence? For example:

> My computer is got/gotten damaged.

Thanks for reading and being interested of my question :).

Comment: In some sense, *got* is more specific than *was*. For example, consider the joke *"Yesterday I was married. Today I am divorced."* It doesn't work if you say *"Yesterday I got married,"* because *"Yesterday I got married"* is not ambiguous.

Comment: The get-passive is more colloquial.

Answer (score 0):

You just cannot say 'my computer is got/gotten damaged'. That is a really bad mistake. What you can say is 'my computer has been damaged'.

You can use get + -ed form to describe things that happen to us, often things which are unfortunate and which we don’t want to happen. I guess this pattern is called 'the get passive':

The cottage got really badly damaged in the floods last year.

Sorry we’re late. The train got delayed for over an hour outside Manchester.

But I don't see any  significant differences if you say:

The cottage was really badly damaged in the floods last year.

Sorry we’re late. The train was delayed for over an hour outside Manchester.

It's just that the verb get/got/gotten is often used in these sentences

Comment: How can something be "badly damaged?"

Comment: @Michael: There is nothing wrong with *"badly damaged"*? Consider a damaged car. The cost of repairs can easily range from less than $500 to over $10,000. If it costs a lot, I assume you would think this was bad ... so it's badly damaged.

Comment: @PeterShor is it me, or did Alex change the answer to "really badly damaged?"  I don't remember seeing "really" there.  I just think it's unnecessary to put an adverb in front of damaged.  I'm probably in the minority (or deserted island) on this one, though.

Comment: @michael: He didn't change anything; I can see that this answer wasn't edited.

Comment: @PeterShor ok...I'm still thinking about the difference between got and was...along with "what the fox say" from that other question...